# SELECT data and UPDATE at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have multiple sources performing the same mysql query to get and perform a job (sources are different php scripts). 
I want to get the job that has most distance to the past so I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY last_done ASC
```

Now my problem is that each source should get unique results, that means if one source gets `job1` this job should get an update to last_done so it is at the bottom of the table again and if a seconds source performs the query it should not get `job1`, instead it should get `job2` and so on.

I have the problem that sometimes if 2 sources call nearly at the same time that they get the same job if I update seperately after the select.

How can I best do it that not 2 sources querying close together get the same job?

Comment: Use transactions and locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
2 - execute the select and update in a single transaction.

Note:
SERIALIZABLE isolation level might be an overkill, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx for details

Comment: Like this? `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION"); mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY last_done ASC"); mysql_query("UPDATE jobs SET last_done = NOW() WHERE job_id = $id"); mysql_query("COMMIT");`

Comment: mysql_query("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE"); then your code as above.

Comment: You might have to set autocommit off: SET autocommit=0;

Comment: depending on what or how do I check if I need it?

Comment: If autocommit is on then you need to set it to off. You can check it but issuing the query "SELECT @@autocommit;"

Comment: Okay I fully implemented this solution but it seems some sources still get the same job, is there anything else that could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should use transaction for this.
one implementation can be
fetch and put record on another table say `job_in_progress`.

and next time you can select the job that is not in `job_in_progress`.

do this transaction in serializable isolation level